# Indicator data plots wrong with request.security(). Pine Script V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm using request.security to get data from higher timeframes in my indicator.
When it plots on historical bars it have strange offset to one bar left.

I've tried to use lookahead but it ruins my plots.

Here's the code:

```
rsi_1W = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", ta.rsi(close, rsiLengthInput))
rsi_1D = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", ta.rsi(close, rsiLengthInput))
rsi_4H = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", ta.rsi(close, rsiLengthInput))
rsi_1H = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", ta.rsi(close, rsiLengthInput))
...
plot(rsi_1W, "RSI (1W)", color.rgb(0, 100, 255))
plot(rsi_1D, "RSI (1D)", color.rgb(0, 100, 200))
plot(rsi_4H, "RSI (4H)", color.rgb(0, 100, 150))
plot(rsi_1H, "RSI (1H)", color.rgb(0, 100, 100))
```

Here's the visual part on 30m timeframe. As you can see there's offset one bar left (02:30) but it should be at the 3:00 bar:

[image: strange offset]

What can I do to ensure that the plot remains consistent and the values are displayed in the correct place?

Comment: Same thing with last bar: plot values offsets to the left (except 1H tf data)

Answer (score 1):

I regularly do the following that solves that problem for me:

```
request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", ta.rsi(close, rsiLengthInput)[1],barmerge.gaps_on, barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

What it does is that it uses past (confirmed) values from the higher timeframe instead of "giving away" the most recent one from the HTF itself. From the lower timeframe point of view, where your chart is, it would be the future, which means that you'll receive incorrect calculation data.

Comment: The problem is that I need values calculated specifically from the current price, because on a higher timeframe they are calculated based on the current closing price. I have already tried your method, but it does not complete the dots and lines on the current bar. However, thanks for the solution.

Comment: I see. Then you'll have to calculate rsi yourself instead of the built-in fn. Check out the method here: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta.rsi. You'll have to tweak the calculation that it is based on the HTF ohlc values but uses current close. I guess you won't even need a single security call for that.

Comment: Thank you @elod008. I left the solution with manual calculation of RSI for last. I even had to make this “crutch”: ```isCurrentWeek = year == year(timenow) and month == month(timenow) and weekofyear == weekofyear(timenow)```